# getting errors in cross-compiling openjdk 11u to aarch64

Tags: java, linux, gcc, arm, openjdk-11

I am trying to cross-compile openjdk 11u to aarch64. I am using following command:

```
bash configure --openjdk-target=aarch64-linux-gnu --disable-warnings-as-errors
```

next I use `make` command to compile openjdk, but iam getting output errors below:

> ```
> ERROR: Build failed for target 'default (exploded-image)' in
> configuration 'linux-aarch64-normal-server-release' (exit code 2)
>
> === Output from failing command(s) repeated here ===
> * For target hotspot_variant-server_libjvm_gtest_objs_BUILD_GTEST_LIBJVM_link:
> /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld:
> /mnt/c/Users/ACER/downloads/jdk11-source/build/linux-aarch64-normal-server-release/hotspot/variant-server/libjvm/objs/macroAssembler_aarch64.o:
> in function `RegSet::operator-(RegSet) const':
> /mnt/c/Users/ACER/downloads/jdk11-source/src/hotspot/cpu/aarch64/register_aarch64.hpp:239:
> undefined reference to `JavaThread::aarch64_get_thread_helper()'
> /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld:
> /mnt/c/Users/ACER/downloads/jdk11-source/build/linux-aarch64-normal-server-release/hotspot/variant-server/libjvm/objs/macroAssembler_aarch64.o:
> in function `MacroAssembler::push(RegSet, RegisterImpl*)':
> /mnt/c/Users/ACER/downloads/jdk11-source/src/hotspot/cpu/aarch64/macroAssembler_aarch64.hpp:518:
> undefined reference to `JavaThread::aarch64_get_thread_helper()'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> * For target hotspot_variant-server_libjvm_objs_BUILD_LIBJVM_link: /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld:
> /mnt/c/Users/ACER/downloads/jdk11-source/build/linux-aarch64-normal-server-release/hotspot/variant-server/libjvm/objs/macroAssembler_aarch64.o:
> in function `RegSet::operator-(RegSet) const':
> /mnt/c/Users/ACER/downloads/jdk11-source/src/hotspot/cpu/aarch64/register_aarch64.hpp:239:
> undefined reference to `JavaThread::aarch64_get_thread_helper()'
> /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld:
> /mnt/c/Users/ACER/downloads/jdk11-source/build/linux-aarch64-normal-server-release/hotspot/variant-server/libjvm/objs/macroAssembler_aarch64.o:
> in function `MacroAssembler::push(RegSet, RegisterImpl*)':
> /mnt/c/Users/ACER/downloads/jdk11-source/src/hotspot/cpu/aarch64/macroAssembler_aarch64.hpp:518:
> undefined reference to `JavaThread::aarch64_get_thread_helper()'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> * All command lines available in /mnt/c/Users/ACER/downloads/jdk11-source/build/linux-aarch64-normal-server-release/make-support/failure-logs.
> === End of repeated output ===
>
> No indication of failed target found. Hint: Try searching the build
> log for '] Error'. Hint: See doc/building.html#troubleshooting for
> assistance.
>
> make[1]: ***
> [/mnt/c/Users/ACER/downloads/jdk11-source/make/Init.gmk:305: main]
> Error 2 make: ***
> [/mnt/c/Users/ACER/downloads/jdk11-source/make/Init.gmk:186: default]
> Error 2
> ```

I don't know how to fix this errors.